# jQuery radio array selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have radio buttons like:

```
<input  type="radio" value="a" name="questions[0]">
<input  type="radio" value="b" name="questions[0]">
<input  type="radio" value="c" name="questions[0]">
<input  type="radio" value="d" name="questions[0]">

<input  type="radio" value="a" name="questions[1]">
<input  type="radio" value="b" name="questions[1]">
<input  type="radio" value="c" name="questions[1]">
<input  type="radio" value="d" name="questions[1]">
```

How do I loop through this with jQuery? I want validate that a response has been given for each question. Thanks.

edit:
or is there even a way to get the length of the questions array?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#myForm input[type=radio]").each(function() {

           //whatever you need     

 });
```

Comment: Can it be more specific to the name, ie questions?

Comment: You can use `$this.attr('name')` in the loop.

Comment: `$(this).attr('name')`

Answer (score 1):

`$('[name="questions[1]"]:checked').val()` gives the checked value of question 1.

Or like below, get the checked value with the name:

```
$('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).val(), $(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Comment: Need to loop through them without knowing how many questions there are if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var rgroups = [];
$('input:radio').each(function (index, el) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < rgroups.length; i++)
    if (rgroups[i] == $(el).attr('name')) return true;
    rgroups.push($(el).attr('name'));
});
rgroups = rgroups.length;

$('#test').click(function () {
    if ($('input:radio:checked').length < rgroups) alert('You must fill in all the fields.');
    else alert("You're done!");
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3t2pH/1/)**