# Select a radio array by name?

Tags: jquery

How can I get the checked value of an array of radio inputs with jQuery, by specifying the name of radio input?

Note I have checked [jQuery radio array selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896168/jquery-radio-array-selector) and [Get radio checked in an array in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899832/get-radio-checked-in-an-array-in-jquery) but they do not allow selections by name.

Example:

```html
<input type="radio" name="user[0]" value="a" />
<input type="radio" name="user[0]" value="b" />
<input type="radio" name="user[0]" value="c" />

<input type="radio" name="user[1]" value="a" />
<input type="radio" name="user[1]" value="b" />
<input type="radio" name="user[1]" value="c" />

<input type="radio" name="user[2]" value="a" />
<input type="radio" name="user[2]" value="b" />
<input type="radio" name="user[2]" value="c" />
```

I've tried:

```
$('input[name=user[*]]:checked').each(function() {
```

It fails - I can't seem to find a way to select by name.

Comment: @freedomn-m no answer on that link selects by array name

Comment: @panthro: whether or not someone understood your question or not, and whether or not their suggestions work, the fact that they are trying to help is no reason to call them bad or insulting names. This discourages others from helping who otherwise might have considered helping you in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector

```js
$("input[name^=user]:checked").each( (i,e) => console.log(e.value));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="user[0]" value="a" />
<input type="radio" name="user[0]" value="b" checked />
<input type="radio" name="user[0]" value="c" />

<input type="radio" name="user[1]" value="a" checked/>
<input type="radio" name="user[1]" value="b" />
<input type="radio" name="user[1]" value="c" />

<input type="radio" name="user[2]" value="a" />
<input type="radio" name="user[2]" value="b" />
<input type="radio" name="user[2]" value="c" checked/>
```